# See server content by vpn connection

Tags: connection, vpn

Hi I'm using a cisco client to connect by vpn. The client tell me that connection is established but now how can I see the folder into the server?

Comment: I'm using cisco anyconnect secure mobil client what info do you need?

Comment: I've never used vpn. My client tell me some routes detail with secured and not secured ip,I've tried to go in this ip but nothing

Comment: what do you mean to map a drive?

Comment: I've tried to map the server but appear an error of dns

Comment: I've tried by ip but nothing works.Yes I'm connecting to my society.By client is connected but if i try to map appear ever error on dns

Comment: The error is: impossible to find host name by dns

Comment: What can I ask to my society?

Comment: So dns error is not my pc problem?

Comment: ok and where and how can I see the content server?

Comment: It's the first time that I tri to connect to this server,and the society told me to connect it by cisco client

Comment: putty tells me:cannot assign request address

Comment: ok ,thanks so much,please wait a minute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42614/discussion-between-stefano-maglione-and-user2196728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once connected to your VPN network using your Cisco VPN client :

```
1) goto start-> execute -> mstsc
2) enter ip address or hostname of the target host
3) enter your credentials : username and password then click ok
4) accept the certificate warning by answering "yes"
5) you are connected !
```

cheers man !